# Array Copy and add new value

Tags: java, arrays, copy

I really don't know how to add in a new value once I copy the array. Does anybody know how I could achieve it?

The output I want:-
**New Array Value: I Love Coding**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
  String originalArray[] = {"I", "Love","Java"};
  String newArray[] = new String[originalArray.length];
           
  System.arraycopy(originalArray, 0, newArray, 0, 2);  
  System.out.println("Original Array Value: " + Arrays.toString(originalArray));
  System.out.println("New Array Value: " + Arrays.toString(newArray) + Coding);

}
```

**And by the way, can I make the array like this:-**

```
String originalArray[] = {"I Love Java"};
//Instead breaking up to {"I","Love","Java"}
//and if change it to one way is the steps going to be the same and the copy ways too?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I really don't know how to add in a new value once I copy the array.

You would have to create a new array, copy all the elements of the old array into the new array, and add the new value. Bear in mind, however, that Java [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is more appropriate for such kinds of operations (*e.g.,* `add`, `remove`, and so on).

Nonetheless, in your case, to get the output **"I Love Coding"** you just need to change your code to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
  String originalArray[] = {"I", "Love","Java"};
  String newArray[] = new String[originalArray.length];
           
  System.arraycopy(originalArray, 0, newArray, 0, 2);  
  newArray[newArray.length - 1] = "Coding";
  System.out.println("Original Array Value: " + Arrays.toString(originalArray));
  System.out.println("New Array Value: " + Arrays.toString(newArray));

}
```

> And by the way, can I make the array like this:-

```
String originalArray[] = {"I Love Java"};
```

Yes you can. However, it would be now an array with a single string "I Love Java", whereas

```
String originalArray[] = {"I","Love","Java"}
```

is an array with three strings, namely `"I", "Love", "Java"`. In this case, you would have to replace the `String` `Java` with `Coding`, without having to copy all the array elements.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String originalArray[] = {"I Love Java"};
    String newArray[] = new String[originalArray.length];
    newArray[0] = originalArray[0].replace("Java", "Coding");
    System.out.println("Original Array Value: " + Arrays.toString(originalArray));
    System.out.println("New Array Value: " + Arrays.toString(newArray));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the point of this exercise is that you can change the last element in your new array

```
newArray[newArray.length - 1] = "Coding";
```

Then if you print newArray like you were printing the original array, you will see the change

Comment: wow ok I never knew that but if I want to add on multiple values is there a simple way to do it.

Comment: @NISHANAJIHAH For adding multiple values you probably want to use an implementation of java.util.List, like ArrayList

Answer (score 1):

you can replace the last element of your array and then printing them as a single String using `String.join` method:

```
String originalArray[] = {"I", "Love","Java"};
originalArray[originalArray.length-1] = "Coding";
System.out.println(String.join(" ", originalArray));
```